# MongoDB schema validation - sub schemas with oneOf or $or

Tags: mongodb, nosql, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have the next validation schema

```
use("bio_db_schema")
```

For Biology

```
const biologyChapterSchema  = {
    bsonType: "object",
    additionalProperties: false,
    properties: {
        "chapter_name": {enum: ["Biologia"]},
        "taxonomias": {
            bsonType: ["array"],
            items: {
                bsonType: "object",
                // required: ["taxonomia_name"],
                additionalProperties: false,
                properties: {
                    "valor": {bsonType: "string"},
                    "taxonomia_name": {bsonType: "string"},
                    "taxonomia_id": {bsonType: "objectId"},
                    "associates": {
                        bsonType: ["array"],
                        items: {
                            bsonType: "object",
                            additionalProperties: false,
                            properties: {
                                "associate_name": {bsonType: "string"},
                                "associate_role": {bsonType: "string"},
                                "associate_id": {bsonType: "objectId"},
                            },
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    }
};
```

For Physics (just for test, i change the "valor" from "string" to "double")

```
const physicsChapterValidation  = {
    bsonType: "object",
    properties: {
        "chapter_name": {enum: ["Fisica"]},
        "estaciones": {
            bsonType: ["array"],
            items: {
                bsonType: "object",
                // required: ["taxonomia_name"],
                additionalProperties: false,
                properties: {
                    "valor": {bsonType: "double"},
                    "estacion_name": {bsonType: "string"},
                    "estacion_id": {bsonType: "objectId"},
                    "associates": {
                        bsonType: ["array"],
                        items: {
                            bsonType: "object",
                            additionalProperties: false,
                            properties: {
                                "associate_name": {bsonType: "string"},
                                "associate_role": {bsonType: "string"},
                                "associate_id": {bsonType: "objectId"},
                            },
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    }
};
```

Schema

```
db.createCollection("projects", {
    validator: {
        $jsonSchema:{
            bsonType: "object",
            // title: "",
            // required: ["chapter_name"],
            additionalProperties: false,
            properties: {
                "_id": {bsonType: "objectId"},
                "project_name": {bsonType: "string"},
                "sub_projects": {
                    bsonType: ["array"],
                    items: {
                        bsonType: "object",
                        additionalProperties: false,
                        properties: {
                            "sub_project_name": {bsonType: "string"}, 
                            "IGA": {bsonType: "string"}, 
                            "sub_project_stage": {
                                bsonType: ["array"],
                                items: {
                                    bsonType: "object",
                                    additionalProperties: false,
                                    properties:{
                                        "sub_project_stage_name": {bsonType: "string"}, 
                                        "chapters": {
                                            bsonType: ["array"],
                                            items: {
                                                oneOf: [
                                                    biologyChapterSchema,
                                                    physicsChapterValidation
                                                ]
                                            }

                                        }
                                    },
                                },
                            },
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    },
});
```

What i expect:

When i insert a document with:

"chapter_name" = "Biologia", it must use the Schema "biologyChapterSchema" (where "valor" is a "string")

"chapter_name" = "Fisica", it must use the Schema "physicsChapterValidation" (where "valor" is a "double")

i use "oneOf" for it,

works for "Biologia", only accept a string, but when i change to "Fisica" it allows "strins", "integers" and allow another properties like "valor2".

I use VSCode extensión and said $or operator doesnt work for $jsonSchema

Those are just a test for my app, I need that they are in variables to make it readable and to be able to keep it over time and add more sub schemas.

Any tips?

For test:

```
db.projects.insertOne({
    "project_name": "Proyecto Fisica",
    "sub_projects": [
        {
            "sub_project_name": "Subproyecto Fisica",
            "IGA": "IGA Fisica",
            "sub_project_stage": [
                {
                    "sub_project_stage_name": "Etapa Fisica",
                    "chapters": [
                        {
                            "chapter_name": "Fisica",
                            "taxonomias": [
                                {
                                    "taxonomia_name": "Taxonomía Fisica",
                                    "taxonomia_id": ObjectId("123456789235"),
                                    "associates": [
                                        {
                                            "associate_name": "Asociado Fisica",
                                            "associate_role": "Rol Biología",
                                            "associate_id": ObjectId("123456789232")
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "valor": "asdasd"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `additionalProperties` in `physicsChapterValidation`.

```
const physicsChapterValidation  = {
    bsonType: "object",
    additionalProperties: false,
    properties: {
        "chapter_name": {enum: ["Fisica"]},
```